# Social feed system design

Tags: google-app-engine, feed

http://twitter.com/#!/ladygaga

When ladygaga tweet 1 message, does it mean to insert 1 data record for EACH of her followers (total 12,221,751)? So totally 12,221,751 records are inserted?

Any clues in designing such a social feed system?

------------------------------- Edit line -------------------------------

Real issue:

Performing SELECT tweet FROM Tweets IN ([FollowingIDs]) is not possible in google app engine, which limiting to a maximum of 30 items in the IN clause

While in app engine it actually means, performing 30 queries in parallel, which is not very wise to do so I guess.

Even if I am allowed to overtake the 30 limits,
what if I am subscribing to 10000 people? I am not sure if there are any performance issues to do it in MYSQL or any other kind of database infrastructure using the "IN clause" 
(the bigtable of app engine is different from MYSQL)

So it is better to use the IN clause to query?
or setting up a UserFeed table for storing the feed relationship?
or 3rd method?

Database/SQL guru please help

Comment: I can't even properly describe the number of levels of annoyance I'm experiencing reading this question. Why wouldn't each user's feed simply select the `top x tweets where tweeterId in usersSubscriptions`? I really want "aaaaaaargh" as a "vote to close" reason.

Comment: Yup, I guess I should added this example with the question before.

My question should be:
Will there be a performance problem if I got 10000 people following?

"SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE owner IN (user1_id, user2_id.....user10000_id)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) from Google I/O 2009 to see how to handle these sort of cases on App Engine with a 'fan out' data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the link & the keyword "fan out"

At 18:52 of the video shows the solution.

While it is really true that 12,221,751 of entries are needed to be written once. (while I am getting a few negative marks)

It should be the best way to implement in App Engine.

But I am still interested the way to do in mySQL, any clues?

Comment: *entries/records means the message indexes

Comment: @user877062 If you want to do it in mySQL, you should ask a separate question tagged with that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you imagine it?

**no**

every people has list of followers

```
ID        |  FOLLOWER__ID
ladygaga  |  genesis
ladygaga  |  user
```

//php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM followers WHERE FOLLOWER__ID = 'genesis';");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $select[] = $row['ID'];
}

$tweets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE owner IN (".implode(",", $select).")");
```